# windows batch: dropping the last "d" in file names

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

what I am trying to do is to change by a windows batch remove the last "d" from all exe with a "d" at the end. For example: 
[stringofwhateverlengthd.exe]
to 
[stringofwhateverlength.exe] (notice the d is missing)

I have tried 
[ren *d.exe *.exe] 
but that does not really work. been looking around but haven't found something that parse file name like that. this can be done with many tools easily but I am looking for the windows batch solution. Thanks.

update: that worked great! thanks. Is there a way to do this while using xcopy without changing the original content of original and destination folder?
for example [xcopy a\*d.exe b\*.exe]

Comment: With regard to updated question - of course there is a way. Why don't you try it? Simply replace the rename command in Andriy's answer with the appropriate xcopy command.

Answer (score 3):

You could try something like this:

```
FOR %%A IN (*.exe) DO (
  SET "name=%%~nA"
  SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
  IF /I !name:~-1! == d (
    RENAME "%%A" "!name:~0,-1!.*"
  )
  ENDLOCAL
)
```

But after putting more thinking into this, like, for instance, [@Marc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1024832/marc) did (thanks!), you could actually come up with something much simpler:

```
FOR %%A IN (*d.exe) DO (
  SET "name=%%~nA"
  SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
  RENAME "%%A" "!name:~0,-1!.*"
  ENDLOCAL
)
```

Comment: Nice. I was putting together something similar.  However, you don't need the if statement if you limit your fileset to `*d.exe`